# IE version of Firefox's Live HTTP Headers

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, header, proxy-server

Is there any free equivalent of Firefox's Live HTTP Headers for IE?

Proxy servers are okay, provided they are free.

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is the gold standard of http debugging proxies.  And it is free (as in beer).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html

Comment: Technically, that is shareware (non-free). I'm looking for free or open source. Nice link though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best tool for the job would be [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Not only you can inspect HTTP, but a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of usinh HTTP watch was to see the HTTP packets in SSL based connection. That is not possible when you use Wireshark.

Comment: Sure it is, if you install the SSL certificate in Wireshark.